# Finding the total area between $x^2-4$ and the y-axis on the interval (0,3)

Tags: calculus, integration

I was assigned to find the total area within $x^2-4$ on the interval of $(0,3)$. The graph looks like this: [image]

The answer key says it is helpful to shift the graph down five and then take the negative integral. Is there a reason not to shift the graph up by four and take the integral like that? When I tried doing this I did not come up with the same answer as they did. Was that simply my own error - or does the method not work?

The definite integral they ended up with was $-\int^3_0x^2-9$. I had $\int^3_0x^2+9$. I know these two things are not the same, but why did their method work while mine did not?

**Why does shifting the graph down work to find the *total area* while shifting it up does not?**

Comment: Could you make sure you ask the precise question you are trying to answer. You need to identify the region for which you want to find the area, and that means identifying all the boundaries.

Comment: But why can't I just move the graph up? If you look at the graph graphed out it looks like it should work - just move the whole thing up four.

Comment: @burt If you move the graph up, the integral gives the area *under* the curve. If instead you move the graph down the integral gives the area *above* the curve. I don't think either of these areas are being asked for in this question so you have to make it more clear what area you are asking for.

Comment: I see - moving the graph up kind of changes the entire question. I would have to also flip the graph in order to keep the same question - so it's easier just to move it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is to figure out the area enclosed by the curve $f(x)=x^2-4$, y axis, and the line $y=f(3)$.

You can do this by moving the curve upward for sure, but the the integral will give you the area below the moved curve, which is not what you want, but the area of the rectangle $3\cdot(f(3)-f(0))$ minus what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they wanted you to find the area of the region between the y axis and the curve (and less than y=5). Maybe the question was poorly worded. In fact, the title itself makes zero sense